# Batch of multidimensional arrays multiplied by a batch of scalers (without loops)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a batch, two data, of multidimensional arrays (3,3,2) as following:

```
batch= np.asarray([
                
              [ 
               [[1,2,3],
               [3,1,1,],
               [4,9,0,]], 

               [[2,2,2],
               [5,6,7],
               [3,3,3]]
              ],
              
              [
               [[2,2,2],
               [5,6,7],
               [3,3,3]], 
               
               [[1,2,3],
               [3,1,1],
               [4,9,0]]
              ]
                  ])
```

correspondingly I have batch, two data, of (1,1,2) as follows

```
scalers = np.asarray([ 
                     
                [
                 [[1]],
                 [[2]]
                                       
                ],

                [
                 [[0]],
                 [[3]]  
                ]
                     
                    ])
```

each dimension in the batch should be multiplied by its corresponding scaler in the scalers array. For example:

```
# the first dimension 

               [[1,2,3],
         1 *   [3,1,1,],
               [4,9,0,]]

# the second dimension 

         2 *   [[2,2,2],
               [5,6,7],
               [3,3,3]]
  
             .
             .
             .

# the last dimension 

          3*   [[1,2,3],
               [3,1,1],
               [4,9,0]]
```

So , the expected output should be like the following:

```
           [
              [
               [[1 2 3],
               [3 1 1 ],
               [4 9 0 ]], 

               [[4 4 4],
               [10 12 14],
               [6 6 6]]
              ],

              [
               [[0 0 0],
               [0 0 0],
               [0 0 0]], 

               [[3 6 9],
               [9 3 3],
               [12 27 0]]
              ]
           ]
```

I was trying to do the following to avoid any loops

```
batch * scalers
```

but it seems it is not correct, I wonder how to do the behavior above

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: It is correct. What's the error/problem you get?

Comment: I added my expectation of how the output should be

Comment: @Ssfff Your code gives it. I have run it and print it by `print(batch * scalers)`. What is the problem???? What did you get?